# trying to write a piecewise function in R

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and want to write a piecewise function , my code is not working , if you can help please comment :

```
   a<-rnorm(1000)

   ifelse(0<a & a<=.3,C=sqrt(30*a),NA)
   ifelse(.3<a & a<=.7,C=5*a+15/10),NA)
   ifelse(.7<a & a<=1,c=8-sqrt(-30*a+30),NA)
```

thank you

Comment: I think you may be looking for something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
a<-rnorm(1000)

C=case_when(0<a & a<=.3 ~ sqrt(30*a),
             0<a & a<=0.3 ~ sqrt(30*a),
             0.3<a & a<=0.7 ~ 5*a+15/10,
             0.7<a & a<=1 ~ 8-sqrt(-30*a+30))
```

Answer (score 5):

Three issues:

1. When used directly as part of a function call’s argument list, `=` isn’ the assignment operator, it’s the syntax for named arguments.
2. Instead of attempting to assign *inside* the `ifelse()` function call argument list, assign the *result*
3. You are currently performing *three distinct* calculations. Really you only want to perform one. To solve this, you need to *nest* your calls:

```
c = ifelse(
    0 < a & a <= 0.3, sqrt(30 * a),
    ifelse(
        0.3 < a & a <= 0.7, 5 * a + 15 / 10,
        ifelse(0.7 < a & a <= 1, 8 - sqrt(-30 * a + 30), NA)
    )
)
```

However, this isn’t very readable. You can use `case_when()` from the ‘dplyr’ package instead to make the code more readable:

```
c = case_when(
    0 < a & a <= 0.3 ~ sqrt(30 * a),
    0.3 < a & a <= 0.7 ~ 5 * a + 15 / 10
    0.7 < a & a <= 1 ~ 8 - sqrt(-30 * a + 30)
    TRUE ~ NA
)
```

Both of these solutions have the unfortunate side-effect of raising warnings due to NaN values (which are caused by the code calculating square roots of negative numbers). See [G. Grothendieck’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66750749/1968) for ways around this issue.

Comment: I so wish base R had some form of case statement like this ... I find nested `ifelse` to be harder to visualize (and therefore maintain), not to mention the liability of `ifelse` being non-`class`-safe. I find `dplyr::case_when` and `data.table::fcase` to be much better in the long run, though again I wish it were found in base R somewhere ...

Comment: @r2evans Yes, base R has a bizarre lack of a useful `switch` expression (the actual `switch()` function is … terrible).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the code in the question:

1. The assignment should be done outside the ifelse, not inside
2. ifelse will first evaluate both legs for all values so if you pass a negative `a` it will try to take the square root of a negative number even if that leg is not chosen.  As a result it is better to avoid using `ifelse` entirely here.
3. nested ifelse's can be hard to follow.

The solutions below avoid `ifelse`. The first one uses if ... else ... . Unlike `ifelse` it only evaluates legs that are actually used.  It only works for scalars but we can use `Vectorize` to transform the scalar function that we write  into a function which accepts vectors.

The second solution separates out the values of `a` which are between 0 and 1 from the others so that we never attempt to take a square root of a negative number and so NA's are not involved in the main computation.  It uses the idiom  cond1 * y1 + cond2 * y2 + ... where y1, y2, ... are numeric non-NA expressions and cond1, cond2, ... are mutually exclusive conditions.  For each vector component only one of the conditions is TRUE so R multiplies the corresponding expression by 1 keeping it and the others by 0 eliminating them.

**1)** Use if/else and Vectorize it. This works even for negative values of a without issuing warnings which might otherwise be issued due to negative square roots and no packages are used.

```
f <- Vectorize(function(a)
  if (0 < a & a <= 0.3) sqrt(30 * a)
  else if (0.3 < a & a <= 0.7) 5 * a + 15 / 10
  else if (0.7 < a & a <= 1) 8 - sqrt(-30 * a + 30)
  else NA)

a <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
c <- f(a)

head(c)
## [1]        NA 0.5477226 0.7745967 0.9486833 1.0954451 1.2247449

tail(c)
## [1] 6.775255 6.904555 7.051317 7.225403 7.452277 8.000000

plot(c ~ a, type = "l")
```

(continued after image)
[image: screenshot]

**2)** Another approach is to do it in a vectorized manner but handle the values leading to an NA separately so that it never attempts to take a square root of a negative number.  Again this uses no packages.

```
f2 <- function(x) {
  ix <- x > 0 & x <= 1
  a <- x[ix]
  replace(NA * x, ix, (0 < a & a <= 0.3) * sqrt(30 * a) +
    (0.3 < a & a <= 0.7) * (5 * a + 15 / 10) +
    (0.7 < a & a <= 1) * (8 - sqrt(-30 * a + 30)))
}

# test
c2 <- f(a)
identical(c, c2)
## [1] TRUE
```